# how to get attribute from any selected object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

for example

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" class="selected">stackoverflow</a>
```

my jquery is here

```
alert($('.selected').attr('href'));
```

but this don't work

How to get attribute from selected object?

Comment: You spelled it scr in one place and src in another. Also, what marius said.

Comment: i'm sorry. wrong writed. not 'src'. this is href

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The anchor tag should have an href attribute, not src.

Answer (score 2):

You say scr in the anchor tag and src in the jquery expression. Also anchors have href not src attributes.